# My custom payment method is getting shown on Admin end, but not on frontend

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-gateway

I am developing a custom payment method for Skrill payment. It is getting shown on admin end but not getting shown on frontend. I am here by attaching all my files.

**etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Payment\Model\CcGenericConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="methodCodes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="skrill" xsi:type="const">Ne\Skrill\Model\Payment::CODE</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="skrill_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Ne\Skrill\Model\ConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

**etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <skrill>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>Ne\Skrill\Model\Payment</model>
                <payment_action>authorize_capture</payment_action>
                <title>Skrill</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            </skrill>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

**Model/Payment.php**

```
    <?php
namespace Ne\Skrill\Model;

class Payment extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Cc
{
    const CODE = 'skrill';

    protected $_code = self::CODE;

    protected $_isGateway                   = true;
    protected $_canCapture                  = true;
    protected $_canCapturePartial           = true;
    protected $_canRefund                   = true;
    protected $_canRefundInvoicePartial     = true;

    protected $_countryFactory;

    protected $_minAmount = null;
    protected $_maxAmount = null;
    protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('USD');

    protected $_debugReplacePrivateDataKeys = ['number', 'exp_month', 'exp_year', 'cvc'];

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Logger $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface $moduleList,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
        array $data = array()
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $extensionFactory,
            $customAttributeFactory,
            $paymentData,
            $scopeConfig,
            $logger,
            $moduleList,
            $localeDate,
            null,
            null,
            $data
        );

        $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Payment capturing
     *
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment
     * @param float $amount
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception
     */
    public function capture(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
    {


        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $payment->getOrder();

        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address $billing */
        $billing = $order->getBillingAddress();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Payment refund
     *
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment
     * @param float $amount
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception
     */
    public function refund(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
    {
        $transactionId = $payment->getParentTransactionId();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Determine method availability based on quote amount and config data
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface|null $quote
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAvailable(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null)
    {

        if (!$this->getConfigData('title')) {
            return false;
        }

        return parent::isAvailable($quote);
    }

    /**
     * Availability for currency
     *
     * @param string $currencyCode
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canUseForCurrency($currencyCode)
    {
        if (!in_array($currencyCode, $this->_supportedCurrencyCodes)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Model/ConfigProvider.php**

```
<?php
namespace Ne\Skrill\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as PaymentHelper;

class ConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    const METHOD_CODE = 'skrill';

    /**
     * @var ResolverInterface
     */
    protected $localeResolver;

    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    protected $config;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer
     */
    protected $currentCustomer;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod[]
     */
    protected $methods = [];

    /**
     * @var PaymentHelper
     */
    protected $paymentHelper;

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ConfigFactory $configFactory
     * @param ResolverInterface $localeResolver
     * @param CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer
     * @param PaypalHelper $paypalHelper
     * @param PaymentHelper $paymentHelper
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
        PaymentHelper $paymentHelper,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->localeResolver = $localeResolver;
        $this->currentCustomer = $currentCustomer;
        $this->paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        $locale = $this->localeResolver->getLocale();

        $config = [
            'payment' => [
                'redirectUrl' => 'https://pay.skrill.com/'

            ]
        ];

        return $config;
    }

    /**
     * Return redirect URL for method
     *
     * @param string $code
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getMethodRedirectUrl($code)
    {
        return $this->methods[$code]->getCheckoutRedirectUrl();
    }
}
```

**view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.html**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- merge payment method renders here -->
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="ne_skrill-payments" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Ne_Skrill/js/view/payment/skrill-payments</item>
                                                                    <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="skrill" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page
```

>

**view/frontend/web/template/payment/skrill-form.html**

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
        name="payment[method]"
        class="radio"
        data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>

        <form class="form" data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode() + '-form'}">
            <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Payment/payment/cc-form' --><!-- /ko -->
        </form>

        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                type="submit"
                data-bind="click: continueToSkrill, enable: (getCode() == isChecked())"
                disabled>
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Continue to Skrill'"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/skrill-payments.js**

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
    ],
    function (
        Component,
        rendererList
    ) {
        'use strict';
        rendererList.push(
            {
                type: 'skrill',
                component: 'Ne_Skrill/js/view/payment/method-renderer/skrill-method'
            }
        );
        /** Add view logic here if needed */
        return Component.extend({});
    }
);
```

**view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-rederer/skrill-methods.js**

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form',
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Payment/js/model/credit-card-validation/validator'
    ],
    function (Component, $) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Ne_Skrill/payment/skrill-form'
            },

            getCode: function() {
                return 'skrill';
            },

            isActive: function() {
                return true;
            },

            validate: function() {
                var $form = $('#' + this.getCode() + '-form');
                return $form.validation() && $form.validation('isValid');
            }

            /** Redirect to skrill */
            continueToSkrill: function () {
                $.mage.redirect(
                    window.checkoutConfig.payment.redirectUrl
                );
            }
        });
    }
);
```